# How to acess or create a azure sas key from node js backend

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to create a 1 min expiry sas key in my azure app service to access blob storage.

How can i create a 1 min expiry sas key and access  in my node js backend

My website frontend access some PDF's from azure blob storage using sas key's But when the front end is trying the download the pdf the request is sent to azure app service blob storage. When this request is made the request header url in the network tab in dev tools the sas key is getting shown. So i want to create a api that will create a sas key for azure blob storage get expired after 1 min and create a new sas key how to access azure app service to create a 1 min expiry sas key is there any npm package

Comment: Why do you want to create an SSH key? To access blob storage with SFTP? Maybe you should look at shared access signatures instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Comment: what did you try to achieve and show the error what you are getting if you tried?

Comment: it is sas key not ssh key

Comment: Does this answer your question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73768592/how-to-create-or-acess-sas-key-for-azure-blob-storage-from-node-js

Comment: it is same question
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73768592/how-to-create-or-acess-sas-key-for-azure-blob-storage-from-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generateBlobSASQueryParameters(BlobSASSignatureValues, StorageSharedKeyCredential) [For More Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-generateblobsasqueryparameters)
.

But first need to add azure blob library `@azure/storage-blob`
[azure blob library for node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=environment-variable-windows)