# How to create or acess sas key for azure blob storage from node js

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

My website frontend access some PDF's from azure blob storage using sas key's
But when the front end is trying the download the pdf the request is sent to azure app service blob storage. When this request is made the request header url in the network tab in dev tools the sas key is getting shown. So i want to create a api that will create a sas key for azure blob storage get expired after 1 min and create a new sas key how to access azure app service to create a 1 min expiry sas key is there any npm package

Comment: What is `ssh key for blob storage`? AFAIK, there is no such thing. Can you please edit your question and provide more details?

Comment: it is sas key not ssh key

Comment: To create a SAS token, you can use [`@azure/storage-blob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) package. The method you are looking for is [`generateBlobSASQueryParameters(BlobSASSignatureValues, StorageSharedKeyCredential)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-generateblobsasqueryparameters).

Comment: you can create or get sas key from azure portal and use in node.js in azure library for blob operations